# Lookup Return value from data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a variable in R and would like to perform look up functionality and return values for  data frame.

Example:

I have variable TaskName and looking for help on returning dates and days between dates from lookup data frame.

Lookup DataFrame

```
Task    Start_Date  End_Date
A       1/1/2017     1/19/2017
B      10/12/2017   12/10/2017
C       5/10/2017    7/17/2017
D      12/12/2017    1/18/2017
```

Comment: can you show your expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

Define data:

```
data <- read.table(text = "Task    Start_Date  End_Date
A       1/1/2017     1/19/2017
B      10/12/2017   12/10/2017
C       5/10/2017    7/17/2017
D      12/12/2017    1/18/2017", header = TRUE)

data
#  Task Start_Date   End_Date
#1    A   1/1/2017  1/19/2017
#2    B 10/12/2017 12/10/2017
#3    C  5/10/2017  7/17/2017
#4    D 12/12/2017  1/18/2017
```

Look up:

```
TaskName <- "B"
data[data$Task == TaskName,]
#  Task Start_Date   End_Date
#2    B 10/12/2017 12/10/2017
```